# Does HTML 5 application cache have any benefit for online apps?

Tags: html, mobile-safari

Does the HTML 5 application (offline) cache have any benefit for online/connected apps?

My page needs to be online to function and is loaded exclusively in a UIWebView as part of an iOS app. This page is loading some large dependencies and I was wondering if I could use the HTML 5 app cache to store these dependencies to avoid relying on the regular browser cache.

So I guess my question is:

When an HTML 5 page is online, does it use the offline cache if a dependency already exists in the HTML5 offline cache?

Comment: Just an advice. This App will be rejected as it just wraps a website into an UIWebView. Edit_: Never mind, advice to myself, read question more carefully :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the HTML5 offline application caching works with online applications, allowing you to benefit from indefinite local caching. For example, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html#concept-appcache-onlinewhitelist about the ability to specifically whitelist particular URLs which *do not* get cached.

Answer (score 1):

Offline web apps make use of a cache manifest as you probably know. Any resources declared in the `CACHE:` section of this file will be stored in the offline cache, and so a user agent that can work with such things will always pull the resources from there—theoretically therefore, there is a performance benefit.

Conversely, any pages / resources specifically listed in the `NETWORK:` section of your cache manifest will *not* get cached locally (throwing errors when offline), and the app will require a connection to load them.

The benefits of using an off-line cache have to be weighed against the additional maintenance you may incur in providing (and updating) the manifest cache file itself, but hey.

Comment: I've implemented the use of local storage for a few files using a manifest file. I used Firefox and according to the "Net" tab in firefox it seems to be going out to my server to fetch the files that are in the local cache.  So either the Net tab is lying or the fact I'm online isn't benefiting from the local storage.

Comment: Well the simple test is to take your app off-line, and see what happens then—it either works or it doesn't. I test off-line apps in Safari and Chrome rather than Firefox, so can't comment on the Firebug network tab, but do you know for sure it's making a _network_ request? Bear in mind that in an off-line app, pages are still referred-to by their full URL, i.e. the originating server name will still be in the browser address bar, even when that server isn't actually being used (because you're off-line).

Comment: Taking the app offline does work but that doesn't prove that when I'm online it is pulling from the local storage.  I'm just trying to determine for sure that there is benefit of the local storage when I'm online.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough: when you go off-line in Firefox, does the net tab still show activity when you navigate through the site? It's possible it will, even though you're not actually connected, because the same URLs are used. If you _do_ see such activity, then that means the same activity when _on-line_ doesn't mean it's ignoring the local cache (you could just sniff the network to be 100% sure). Given that the server should be returning a 200 when on-line, these performance considerations are pretty border-line anyway.